# Can you generate documentaton for Twig views in PHP?

Tags: php, view, twig, doxygen, documentation-generation

I would like to use my views to generate a style guide *(What are they called now?  Design systems?)*.  Something akin to JavaDocs for Twig templates, so at the top of the view ...

```
{#
    # Button

    A standard button

    ## Usage
    Buttons should be used in X Y Z situations.

    @author John Smith <john.smith@megacorp.uk>
    @copyright Megacorp UK, 2099
    @version 1.0.3
    @param array    data    .....
    @param string   text    Button text
    @param string   type    Button type (submit, button, ..)
    ...
#}
<button <!-- ... -->>
   <!-- more code -->
</button>
```

Is there a tool or something to do that?

Comment: How would the output have to look like (image?) based on the above input.

Comment: Well, that's the ideal situation of course - but I'd imagine it'd be tricky to implement automatically (perhaps allow @image, <img> or similar).

Outputting the text documentation would be perfectly adequate, though.  Just wondering if there's a quick way to generate documentation that's kept with the code (i.e. is more likely to be maintained)!

Comment: It is a bit unclear how things would look like. I think that in doxygen you might need something like `INPUT_FILTER` to convert the code to a usable format for doxygen and proceed from there (don't forget the `EXTENSION_MAPPING`).